# Corner Stitching Datastructure, Any Open Source Implementations?

Tags: c++, language-agnostic, open-source, data-structures, 2d

I recall learning about the corner-stitched data structure a number of years ago and have been fascinated with it ever since.  It originated with a [paper by Ousterhout](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1983/6352.html).

I've searched and not been able to find a free/open implementations.  I'd prefer a C++ implementation, but at this point would accept any pointers people might have.

Note: a corner-stitched data structure is a way to store 2 dimensional, rectangluar data, explicitly maintaining the whitespace between inserted elements.  This is as opposed to a quad-tree which just stores the inserted data elements.  There are many trade-offs, I'm mostly interested in an implementation - but would also accept alternatives that have similar properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ousterhout's own software package **Magic** implements corner stitching. The C source code is available BSD-licensed at http://opencircuitdesign.com/magic.